# How to create an array of CCColor?

Tags: xcode, cocos2d-iphone

I use cocos2dV3 i create some  color:

```
#define color_red ccc3(253, 93, 70)
#define color_green ccc3(138,233,145)
#define color_yellow ccc3(230,219,37)
#define color_violet ccc3 (153,93,181)
#define color_turquoise ccc3(138,188,255)
#define color_default ccc3(225,225,225)
```

How i can save it as array : NSArray , NSmutableAraay ... ?

```
 NSmutableArray * _arrColors =[[NSMutableArray alloc]init];

    [_arrColors addObject:color_turquoise];
```

When i create array it alway show errors : " Sending 'ccColor3B' (aka 'struct _ccColor3B') to parameter of incompatible type 'id'"

What i do worng ?

Comment: You can't. A ccColor3B is apparently a struct. You cannot put a struct into an NSArray because a struct is not an object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using cocos2d does not relieve you of the responsibility of knowing Objective-C. A ccColor3B is not an object - it is a struct - so it cannot be put into an NSArray. You could, if you really want to do this, wrap it in an object, something like this perhaps:

```
ccColor3B c = color_turquoise;
[_arrColors addObject:[NSValue valueWithBytes:&c objCType:@encode(ccColor3B)]];
```

Comment: Thanks you , struct can't be put into an NSarray .